# MacBook Pro 2016 bottom of key loose

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I removed the T key on my MacBook Pro 2016 to clean under it, and when I tried to put it back on, the top part snapped on fine, but the bottom part wouldn't. I probably just put the key in wrong. Can someone guide me in the correct way to put the key back on? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCT-CldP_r4) was very helpful for me while cleaning my MBP keyboard (late 2015)